# Run script in SQL Server CE database

Tags: sql-server-ce

I've used the `Databases > Tasks > Generate Script` functionality in SQL Server Management Studio Express to generate and save a few tables to a script in a `.sql` file. Now that I have the `.sql` script I'd like to run I've added a SQL Server CE database to the `App_Data` folder of my ASP.NET application but I can't seem to figure out how to run the script in my `.sql` file on the SQL Server CE database.

By the way, I've already tried to copy the SQL Server CE database from my application to the folder my other database files are stored in and attempted to attach the SQL Server CE database to the "Databases" in my SQL Server Management Studio Express. However we're evidently unable to attach SQL Server CE databases. This means, evidently we're also unable to run scripts on a SQL Server CE databases in SSMSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the Toolbox (also available as single .exe standalone - hardly bloated), or a similar tool, since the script generated by SSMS is not Sql CE compatible. My tools can be pointed to a SQL Server database, and create a script in the correct syntax - MS provides no such "downsizing" feature.

Comment: EriKEJ, thank you for your reply. We all appreciate your contribution. I'll be using SQL Server Compact Toolbox, it solves the problem.

Comment: I have to take back my previous comment in that SQL Server Compact Toolbox does not solve the stated problem. I downloaded the standalone and tried to run the script generated from SSMS and unfortunately received error after error based (as far as I know) on the limitations of SQLCE. `ANSI_NULLS/QUOTED_IDENTIFIER/[nvarchar](max)/PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` and so on. So I'm back to "square one." Maybe I'll have to look for an .mdf to .sdf conversion tool.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Use the Toolbox to create the script, not SSMS, as I state in my answer. Then run that script with the Toolbox. See http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/02/migrating-databases-between-sql-server.html

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link however after connecting to a "membership" `.mdf` database through SQL Server Compact Toolbox by clicking 1) the root node 2) selecting "Script SQL Database Schema and Data ...I received an error containing multiple specific errors. I've added the error above.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug, it has been fixed in the latest release (3.0.0.7)

Comment: Very cool, thanks Erik. This toolbox couldn't have been a breeze to build so thank you. I downloaded "Standalone 3.0.0.7 for SQL Server Compact 4.0" from [codeplex](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases) then executed the script generated in SQLCE Toolbox of my .mdf database and voila! ...instant rock-a-thon! Some serious rock and roll!